# How to insert a line break or a return within a Note TEI XML

Tags: xml, tei

I'm writing up annotations and I'm currently trying to format them. I'm working in Oxygen and I've tried both  and  and obviously just hitting enter within the annotation but none of them are working unfortunately. 
Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> [**`<lb/>`**](http://tei.oucs.ox.ac.uk/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-lb.html) (line break) marks the start of a new (typographic) line in some edition or version of a text.

**Source:** [*P5: Guidelines for Electronic Text Encoding and Interchange*](http://tei.oucs.ox.ac.uk/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/)